# Passing a click event to a function within a Promise tells me to use event.persist(), How?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have these 2 functions.  I tried to pass the event "e" through to the promise, but in the "handleOnClick" function, e is null because it's out of the "this" scope.  so I assigned the event to "this.clickEvent" and passed that instead, but now I get this long message about synethetic events and event.persist().

How do I fix this?

```
handleClick( e ) {
  this.clickEvent = e;
  somePromise( param1, param2 ).then( result => {
    handleOnClick( this.clickEvent, param1, param2 );
  });
}

handleOnClick( e, param1, param2 ) {
  if ( e.shiftKey ) { // get the below message in console here }
}
```

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `shiftKey` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See fb.me/react-event-pooling for more information.

Comment: Just call `.persist()`  http://duncanleung.com/fixing-react-warnings-synthetic-events-in-setstate/

Comment: http://duncanleung.com/fixing-react-warnings-synthetic-events-in-setstate/

Comment: where do i call .persist()?  going to read what you linked right now

Comment: okay i see what to do now through the article you linked, thanks SLaks going to try it right now.

Comment: @SLaks it worked.  provide an answer and i'll give u credit thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error tells you, just call `event.persist()` (on whatever your event is).

[More examples](http://duncanleung.com/fixing-react-warnings-synthetic-events-in-setstate/)

Comment: The link is broken. That's the problem with posting link-only answers.